# Android : Some time service is stop in some application

Tags: java, android, service

Now i am working in Android service. i make folder observer in service . so when any movement in folder than some event will be generate.

here is code:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();                                               
    Log.v(TAG, "oncreate"); 
    Log.e(TAG, "onStart");

}   

@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.v(TAG, "onStart");

    pathToWatch = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString() +"/Screenshots/";                

            observer = new FileObserver(pathToWatch) {
                @Override                         
                public void onEvent(int event, final String file) {

                    if(event == FileObserver.CREATE)
                    {
                        String Path= pathToWatch+file;
                        Intent intent = new Intent();                                       
                        intent.setAction(MY_ACTION);                                                                    
                        intent.putExtra("DATAPASSED", Path);
                        sendBroadcast(intent);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Log.d(TAG, "File Else [" + pathToWatch + file + "]");
                    }              
                }           
            };                     
            observer.startWatching();   


    return Service.START_STICKY;
    }
```

My issue is:

1. when first time launch application that time its not work but second time lunch the application its work properly.
2. After some time my service is automatically stop so my requirement is service is run long time not automatically stop.

Any one have idea of my Issue?

thank you in Advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android OS is free to kill any service depending on how much memory is left to run more important things (system processes, foreground app, visible service), see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html:

> Note this means that most of the time your service is running, it may
>   be killed by the system if it is under heavy memory pressure. If this
>   happens, the system will later try to restart the service. An
>   important consequence of this is that if you implement
>   onStartCommand() to schedule work to be done asynchronously or in
>   another thread, then you may want to use START_FLAG_REDELIVERY to have
>   the system re-deliver an Intent for you so that it does not get lost
>   if your service is killed while processing it.
>
> ...
>
> A started service can use the startForeground(int, Notification) API
>   to put the service in a foreground state, where the system considers
>   it to be something the user is actively aware of and thus not a
>   candidate for killing when low on memory. (It is still theoretically
>   possible for the service to be killed under extreme memory pressure
>   from the current foreground application, but in practice this should
>   not be a concern.)

So the solution is clear, either

1. call [startForeground()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29), or
2. design your Service to be robust by using [START_FLAG_REDELIVERY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_FLAG_REDELIVERY)

---

Edit:
Here's an example of using startForeground():

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startForeground(
        NOTIF_MONITORING,
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification,
                        Notification.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setLargeIcon(
                        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                                R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setTicker(getString(R.string.notif_ticker))
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(info)
                .setContentIntent(
                        PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0))
                .build());
```

Note that this would cause a persistent notification to be displayed in Notification, this is a required since around 4.0, to prevent malicious apps running stealthily in the background. If you find this requirement undesirable, you'll have to go with the START_FLAG_REDELIVERY route.

Comment: So can you please help me how to use startForground() for start service?

Comment: Its work but first time lunch the application its not work...@Kai

Comment: @Chirag Does Log.v(TAG, "onStart"); run when you launch it for the first time?

Comment: i think the flag name is START_REDELIVER_INTENT which will be returned inside onStartCommand()

Answer (score 0):

You have to use startForeground() in your service , so that we can prevent  killing service due to memory low or any configure  from android platform.

example,

```
        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("TOPAZ-PACS")
            .setContentText("")
            .setSmallIcon(com.emdsys.android.pacs.R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .build();
      notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
      startForeground(1234, notification);
```

in your oncreate() of service class.